# Julia -- How to Put a Substring/String in an Array into its Own Separate Array

Tags: arrays, types, julia

I'm working on one of the AOC problems and have spent hours trying to figure this out.

I have an array of arrays of substrings created by reading a file and using the "split" function. Each individual subarray has two elements:

```
julia> col[3]
2-element Array{SubString{String},1}:
 "SMS"
 "GFS"

julia> col[3][2]
"GFS"
```

I want to make the last element of each subarray be an array containing the last element. I tried to use a loop like this:

```
for i in col
         i[2] = [i[2]]
       end
ERROR: MethodError: Cannot `convert` an object of type Array{SubString{String},1} to an object of type SubString{String}
```

I've tried several workarounds but to no avail. But it seems to half-work if I access the subarrays one at a time.

```
Julia> col[3][2]
"GFS"

julia> [col[3][2]]
1-element Array{SubString{String},1}:
 "GFS"
#creates a separate array like I want, but an error gets thrown if I try to assign it
julia> col[3][2] = [col[3][2]]
ERROR: MethodError: Cannot `convert` an object of type Array{SubString{String},1} to an object of type SubString{String}
```

I'm a Julia newbie and suspect the error has something to do with types, but despite a ton of research, the solution to what seems to be an easy problem is escaping me. I never post here unless I feel I've exhausted all other paths, so I'd appreciate any help or direction.

Comment: `x = [[c[1],[c[2]]] for c in col]` will do what you want, but I think it might not be what you should do...

Comment: Thanks everyone. My goal in the end was to create a dictionary using the values in col, and I was able to get what I wanted this way: `ks = [i[1] for i in col]
vs = [String[i[2]] for i in col]
d = Dict{String, Array}(ks .=> vs)` Similar to your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a new outer array and fill it. Both the inner arrays and outer arrays are typed, so they can ONLY contain one type. You probably want the inner array to be of type `Array{Any, 1}`, and the outer array should then have that type as its element type.